# Issue with adding a JPanel to JFrame: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am having an issue with my compiler when I hit run it gives me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.java:426)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1120)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:998)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:562)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
    at DealerWindow.<init>(DealerWindow.java:36)
    at DealerWindow.main(DealerWindow.java:98)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Which seems to be telling me that on line 35 it cannot add to layout because the constraint must be string or null

Here is my code(Yes every bit of it):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DealerWindow extends JFrame{
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH  = 450;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 338;

    public DealerWindow(){

        //Sets the title
        setTitle("Welcome to X");

        //Set the window size
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        // Specify an action for the close button
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Set BorderLayout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // creates a Panel that will contain a Label that will contain the users image
        JPanel innerPanelCenter = new JPanel();
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon();
        JLabel Label = new JLabel(icon);

        //Sets Layout and adds the label and innerPanel
        innerPanelCenter.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        innerPanelCenter.add(Label);
        add(innerPanelCenter,new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        // creates innerPanelRight to go on the West side of the form
        JPanel innerPanelRight = new JPanel();
        innerPanelRight.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //Buttons for innerPanelRight
        JButton openButton = new JButton("Open");

        //Labels for innerPanelRight
        JLabel makeLabel = new JLabel("Make: ");
        JLabel modelLabel = new JLabel("Model: ");
        JLabel yearLabel = new JLabel("Year: ");
        JLabel commentsLabel = new JLabel("Comments: ");

        //TextFields for innerPanelRight
        JTextField makeTextField = new JTextField();
        JTextField modelTextField = new JTextField();

        //ComboBoxes for innerPanelRight and fills the ComboBox
        JComboBox yearComboBox = new JComboBox();
        for (int i = 1900; i >2013; i++){
           yearComboBox.addItem(i);
        }

        //TextAreas for innerPanelRight
        JTextArea commentsTextArea = new JTextArea();
        commentsTextArea.setLineWrap(true);

        //Creates JPanels for each user field and sets Layouts
        JPanel makePanel = new JPanel();
        makePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel modelPanel = new JPanel();
        modelPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel yearPanel = new JPanel();
        yearPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel commentsPanel = new JPanel();
        commentsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //adds components to the respective Panels
        yearPanel.add(yearLabel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        yearPanel.add(yearComboBox,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        makePanel.add(makeLabel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        makePanel.add(makeTextField,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        modelPanel.add(modelLabel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        modelPanel.add(modelTextField,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        commentsPanel.add(commentsLabel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        commentsPanel.add(commentsTextArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //add the button and 4 component panels to the innerPanelRight
        innerPanelRight.add(openButton);
        innerPanelRight.add(yearPanel);
        innerPanelRight.add(makePanel);
        innerPanelRight.add(modelPanel);

        //add innerPanelRight to the west side of the frame
        add(innerPanelRight,BorderLayout.WEST);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new DealerWindow();
    }
}
```

The error states the issue is on line 35 which is:

```
add(innerPanelCenter,new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a valid layout constraint. Replace

```
add(innerPanelCenter,new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
```

with

```
add(innerPanelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: 1+  Last up-vote of the day used up on this answer! At Blaine: you'll want to read the layout manager tutorial. It's all explained there and works a lot better than throwing random code at the wall and waiting to see what sticks.